# Mixing $(this) selector with [attribute*=value]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been digging documents and the forum to find a way to mix both selectors, but I didn't. I only know how to select all elements that `[attribute*=value]` (ex: `$("[attribute*='value']")`), or all HTML elements from the same type (Ex: `$("input[name*='value']")`. How do I select something like `$("$(this)[name*='value']")`.

**EDIT:**

In this case, I'm using the selector .class. But just for the propose of example. I need to select both "more-bed" buttons. But all buttons of class "more" are firing the alert.

```js
$(".more").click(function() {
  if ($(".more").filter('[name*=bed]')) {
    alert("bed")
  }
});
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="more" name="bed-test">more-bed</button>
<button class="more" name="bed-check">more-bed</button>
<button class="less" name="bed-test">less-bed</button>
```

Comment: What's your html?

Comment: I'm gonna post an example. I was looking for an answer to apply to any HTML, and not a solution for a specific case.

Comment: Can't see that including html would help this question - some people just put that on if there's no html.

Comment: Short answer: you can't use `this` in a selector *string*.  To do what you need, you would use `.filter()` - `$(this).filter("[name]")`

Comment: Exactly @freedomn-m!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not()`

```js
$('[name=bed-test]').not('.less').on('click', () => console.log('yay'))
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="more" name="bed-test">more-bed</button>
<button class="less" name="bed-test">less-bed</button>
<button class="more" name="bath-test">more-bath</button>
```

You can also use `filter()`

```js
$('.more').on('click', e => $(e.currentTarget).filter('[name=bed-test]').css('width', '300px'))
```

```css
button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="more" name="bed-test">more-bed</button>
<button class="less" name="bed-test">less-bed</button>
<button class="more" name="bath-test">more-bath</button>
```